# Cognos SDK Parameters to run a report

Tags: java, sdk, cognos-11

I am trying to write a java application to access a report in Cognos 11.   I am trying to pass a parameter into the report.  For now, it's proof of concept so it is hardcoded string.  Problem is when I use this method, the output HTML file is the parameter page and not the underlying report.

```
        ParameterValue parameters[] = new ParameterValue[1];
        parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
        parameters[0].setName("pFundingDescription");

        ParmValueItem[] pvi = new ParmValueItem[1];
        SimpleParmValueItem item = new SimpleParmValueItem();
        item.setUse("AUTO PAYMENTS");
        pvi[0] = item;

        parameters[0].setValue(pvi);
```

The parameter name in the report is "pFundingDescription" and it is a mutli-select which includes the option "AUTO PAYMENTS".

How do I make this work?

ps: I was looking at this question to get as far as I did: [Cognos v11 SDK Parameter Passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52210133/cognos-v11-sdk-parameter-passing)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. My guess is that the prompt page is either being triggered by a report property to show it or required parameters not being present and it, therefore, prompting for them.

To experiment further, can you remove other prompts (*or make sure any that can't be removed are 'optional'*) and change the report properties to instruct it not to prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method that will process any array of ints (C#) i assume you can updates this to work in Java. Check this out and see if it helps.

```
private static parameterValue LoadMultipleInts(string varName, List<int> values)
    {
        try
        {
            var parameter = new parameterValue();
            parameter.name = varName.Trim();
            //Array size should equal number of id's passed in
            parmValueItem[] pvi = new parmValueItem[values.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
            {

                simpleParmValueItem item = new simpleParmValueItem();
                item.use = values[i].ToString();
                item.display = values[i].ToString();
                item.inclusive = true;
                pvi[i] = item;
            }
            parameter.value = pvi;
            return parameter;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```